# Call method of python class from C++ code

Tags: python, c++, linux, boost, boost-python

For example let us consider `python` class with the following structure in file`mult.py`.

`mult.py`

```
class Mult: 
      def __init__(self, first, second):
            self.a = first 
            self.b = second 

      def multiply(self):
            c = self.a*self.b
            print 'The result of', self.a, 'x', self.b, ':', c
            return c
```

**How could we call `multiply` method from class above in `C++` Code?** (But without `PyRun_SimpleString()` function)

`main.cpp`

```
#include<python2.7/Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
     Py_Initialize();
     int a {10};
     int b {5};
     ... CODE HERE (a*b using python function)
     Py_Finalize();
}
```

I was looking a solution in `Cython` and `boost.python` but could not find it.

Additional links:

- [First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577676/using-python-objects-in-c)
- [Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055443/boost-python-how-to-pass-a-c-class-instance-to-a-python-class)

Comment: I think it's a duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/q/3286448/10077

Comment: @FredLarson, thank you for your link (It is very helpful). But i didn't find how to get access (what function)  to class (which in `python` module) and after that call some method of this class. If you could give a link to simple example, this would be great.

Comment: I think you'd just import it using something like `PyObject* mult_module = PyImport_ImportModule("mult");`. There are examples in the answers to the linked question.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39813301/1741542 is better suited, because it creates an object and then uses it.

Comment: @OlafDietsche thank you very much for this link. It helps a lot :)

Comment: I found the answer on russian stackoverflow: [link to answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785574/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-python-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-c/785927#785927)

Comment: I can read the code, although I must skip the Russian part ;-)